# Variable keeps getting set to NULL after function in DLL

Tags: c++, qt, dll, dll-injection

I need valid data to be in the global variable `QObject *p`. However, assigning anything to this variable inside of a function works within the scope of the function, but after the function returns, `p` is set back to NULL, even though `p` is global. Here is my code:

```
    #include ... // various includes

    // p is NULL
    QObject *p;
    HHOOK hhk;

    BOOL WINAPI DllMain(__in HINSTANCE hinstDLL, __in DWORD fdwReason, __in LPVOID  lpvReserved)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT *mouseInfo = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;

        QMouseEvent::Type type;
        QPoint pos = QPoint(mouseInfo->pt.x, mouseInfo->pt.y);
        Qt::MouseButton bu;
        Qt::MouseButtons bus;
        Qt::KeyboardModifiers md = Qt::NoModifier;
        ... // very large switch statement
        // here is where i need some valid data in p
        QCoreApplication::postEvent(p, new QMouseEvent(type, pos, bu, bus, md));
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    // note: MOUSEHOOKSHARED_EXPORT is the same as __declspec(dllexport)
    // this function is called by the application that loads the dll
    extern "C" MOUSEHOOKSHARED_EXPORT void install(QObject *mParent, DWORD threadID, HINSTANCE hInst)
    {
        p = mParent; // p is assigned here and keeps the value of mParent untill the function returns
        hhk = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, MouseProc, hInst, threadID);
    } // after this function returns, p is NULL

    extern "C" MOUSEHOOKSHARED_EXPORT void uninstall()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk);
    }
```

I have tried various data structure "workarounds" such as using `struct` `typedef` etc... i can't seem to get this to work. All i need is for `p` to retain the value of `mParent`.

EDIT:
Here is where i execute install()

```
    // EarthWidget is a class that is derived from QWidget(which is derived from QObject)
    void EarthWidget::LoadAll()
    {
        HINSTANCE DLLinst = LoadLibrary("MouseHook.dll");
        ... // get functions in DLL using GetProcAddress & typedefs, etc...
        // i pass in 'this' as mParent
        install(this, GetWindowThreadProcessId((HWND)earthplugin->GetRenderHwnd(), NULL), DLLinst);
        // note that GetWindowThreadProcessId does work and does return a valid thread id, so no problem there
     }
```

EDIT:
Found out what was wrong. The `this` pointer becomes out of scope when `install` is executed, therefore `mParent`, being a `QObject`, initializes itself to `NULL`. Thus `p` becomes `NULL`. `this` comes back into scope when `install` returns, however, at a completely different memory address. The solution, after extensive debugging and headaches, would be to create a class member function that takes a `QObject` as a parameter and passes that into `install` instead of `this`. Whatever you pass into that function must last as long as you need the DLL to last. That, or, you can create your own copy constructor that performs a deep copy.

Comment: Where is this `QObject* p`? You should add the code from where you are calling this function.... ooops. I see it at the top there. Sorry.

Where are you calling `install` from? The pointer you pass could be NULL. You are not checking.

Comment: I think it is not NULL, im acctually passing it (and calling `install`) from the application. Im calling install from a method within a class that passes `this` as `mParent` (the class is derived from QObject)          `install = (Install)GetProcAddress(DLLinst, "install");
    uninstall = (Uninstall)GetProcAddress(DLLinst, "uninstall");

    install(this, GetWindowThreadProcessId((HWND)earthplugin->GetRenderHwnd(), NULL), DLLinst);`

Comment: That edit about `this` going out of scope during the call to install and coming back into scope at a different address makes no sense.  Are you saying all of that happens during a single call to `LoadAll` prior to returning from `LoadAll`?

Comment: Yes, this all happens during `LoadAll`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a shallow copy of that parameter mParent.  At some point, that pointer must be getting set to null (or you're passing it as null), which will result in p also becoming null.

Comment: I don't think that `mParent` is getting set to NULL, although i'm not entirely sure. `mParent` is acctually a pointer to a `this`. The object that is created with that `this` exists almost entirely through the life of the program.

Comment: I would still keep a watch on it, only because of the shallow copy.  Given the code that you posted, it's the only thing I personally can come up with.

Comment: I think i know whats happening, and your right. `mParent` points to `this`. Subsequently, when i execute `install()` and leave the class function scope, `this` is deleted. Therefore in order to save its own skin, `mParent` reestablishes itself as `NULL` (`QObjects` do that to prevent dangling pointers), thus assigning `NULL` to `p`. After `install` is finished running, execution goes back to `EarthWidget::LoadAll()` and `this` is reastablished, but, at a different memory address, leaving `mParent` and `p` as `NULL`, and leaving me with a splitting headache.

Comment: There you go, then!  Try deep copying the pointer instead of doing a shallow.

Answer (score 1):

Is your call to `install` actually happening in the dll address space (in the debugger, step into the call and check the addresses in the callstack)?  Is `install` defined in a header file or is that extract from a source file?  If in a header, it's been inlined into your exe so the dll version of p is never set.  This would happen without any linker warning since there are two independent binaries using the same source.

Is `MOUSEHOOKSHARED_EXPORT` defined in your app?  Probably needs to be `MOUSEHOOKSHARED_IMPORT` for the app (but not the dll).

Comment: I isn't. It only gets loaded once, then unloaded when i'm done with it.

Comment: `install` is extracted from a source file, it is not defined in the header file. `MOUSEHOOKSHARED_EXPORT` works as such:        `#if defined(MOUSEHOOK_LIBRARY)
         #  define MOUSEHOOKSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
         #else
         #  define MOUSEHOOKSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
         #endif`                                             `MOUSEHOOKSHARED_EXPORT` is defined in the header file for the DLL... Should i `#include` the DLL header file in the application?

Comment: @Nolan: what's your `install` typedef?

Comment: `typedef void (*Install)(QObject* mParent, DWORD threadID, HINSTANCE hInst);`

Comment: @Nolan: in your edit where you added the call to `install` you used `install` instead of `Install` - typo or bug?

Comment: The `typedef` is `Install(QObject *, DWORD, HINSTANCE)` however the actual function is declared as `Install install;` then initialized as `install = (Install*)GetProcAdress(...);` and finally executed using `install()`. `Install` isn't the function itself, just its type.

Comment: @Nolan: Missed your previous question about the dll header file.  Since you are calling install and uninstall via GetProcAddress, you don't need to #include the dll header file in the app.  I'm running out of ideas.  Might load the exe into depends.exe (or use dumpbin) and confirm that it is not exporting any of the symbols that the dll is also exporting.

Comment: Actually i figured it out with extensive debugging, i posted the reason in a comment to MGZero, at the bottom of the page (for me at least). It had to do with the `this` pointer being out of scope when `install` is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you exporting the global in the DLL and then importing it in the program? If you are not, or not doing it correctly, you probably have two `p` objects: one in the DLL and one in the program. You can confirm this by checking the address of `p`.

Rather than a global variable consider using an exported function in the DLL that returns the needed reference/pointer. At the very least name it something more descriptive (unless it was just renamed for the purpose of asking this question).

Comment: Hehe, i acctually named it `p` just because i was trying so many things with it that i got tired of writing a descriptive name. Anyway, im not sure what you mean by exporting the global in the DLL, does that mean i should add __declspec(dllexport) in front of it?

Comment: Nevermind, i see what you mean. I need to be able to get access to whatever value `mParent` has within the callback, thats why i need a global variable (or at least i think i need a global variable). I can't pass `mParent` into the callback, so i don't know any other way other than using a global variable.